# How to check if a page has angular or not using protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

Is there a way to check using protractor if the page has angular enabled or not?

I have some links in a page and clicking on some links will render an angular page and some links will be render a non-angular page.

After clicking on a link, I need to assert on the title of the page that is opened. Protractor tests fail if the page is non-angular. So is there is a dynamic way to check if a page is angular or not through code? Some logic like this

```
    if (angular){
        //do some actions
    } else {
       browser.ignoresynchronization = true
       // do some actions
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For angular 1.x, there is a global variable `window.angular`, for angular 5 and later, the global variable is `window.ng`

```
browser.executeScript("return !!(window.angular || window.ng);")
    .then(function(isAngular){
        if(isAngular) {

        }
        else {

        }
    });
```